# Android: Проблема с кодировкой в HttpClient

Tags: android, java, httpclient

Использую HttpClient, чтобы получать исходный код страниц.

Вместо русского языка вот такая фигня.

[image]

Как решить?

Comment: У HttpClient'а проблем с кодировкой нет, он вообще не учитывает кодировку. Могу предположить, что вы неправильно превращаете массив байт в строку. Приведёте код?

Answer (score 2):

Решать так, только в данном случае нужно проследить, чтобы у исходной страницы codepage была UTF-8. Ну или поменять ее в коде на другую приемлемую кодировку (могут быть нюансы).

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(MenuSalesTextUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    MenuSalesTex = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

P.S. Сори за некропостинг, мало ли, может кому приходится. :)